# pythonにおけるデータ型のエラー

Tags: python3, データ構造, 情報理論

pythonのgurobiにおいて,

```
g={(1,1):1,(1,2):1,(1,3):1,(1,4):1,
   (2,1):1,(2,2):1,(2,3):1,(2,4):1,
   (3,1):1,(3,2):1,(3,3):1,(3,4):1,
   (4,1):1,(4,2):1,(4,3):1,(4,4):1,
   (5,1):1,(5,2):1,(5,3):1,(5,4):1,
  }

P,G=multidict({1:[1,2,3,4],2:[1,2,3,4],3:[1,2,3,4],4:[1,2,3,4],5:[1,2,3,4]})
W,H=multidict({1:[1,2,3,4,5],2:[1,2,3,4,5],3:[1,2,3,4,5],4:[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

g(i,j)の行列の1の時を, G_iとして,iごとに,行列に格納し, H_jとして, jごとに格納しようとしました.
するとエラーメッセージで,

```
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

P,GとW,Hをどう変更すればよいのかわかりません.
教えてください.

Comment: 「g(i,j)の行列の」の文がよくわかりません。が, `gurobipy.multidict()` では, キーとそれぞれの内容の項目が分解されるようなので, 1つ目の multidictは keyと 4項目で 5つ分, 2つ目の行は 6つ分になり, 左辺の項目が足りません。(もしも `G` にすべての辞書を取り込むのなら `*G` と指定すれば OK) (`G_1`,`G_2` … と指定したいなら, `G_4`まで, `H`は `H_5`まで記すと良いでしょう)

Comment: すみません、解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: (仮に) `*H` として 5つ分の辞書を取り込んだなら, `H`は listであり, `for d in H` と記述すると一つずつ辞書を取り出すことになります。`for j in W: print([d[j] for d in H])` でたぶん望む数値が得られるのでは？ `x`はたぶん `addVar` で指定したものだろうけど, 普通に式を指定できるのなら, `x[d[j],j] for d in H` で可能かも？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(解決してるようなので, 回答として記しておきます)

質問の「g(i,j)の行列の」の文がよくわかりません。が, [`gurobipy.multidict()`](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_multidict.html) では, キーとそれぞれの内容の項目が分解されるようです
なので, 1つ目の multidict指定の行は keyと 4項目で 5つ分, 2つ目の行は 6つ分になり, 左辺の項目が足りません。

- もしも `G` にすべての辞書を取り込むのなら `*G` と指定すれば OK
- `G_1`, `G_2` … と指定したいなら, `G_4`まで, `H`は `H_5`まで記すと良いでしょう

---

値を取り出す場合:
`*H` として 5つ分の辞書を取り込んだなら, `H`は listであり, 次のように指定すると一つずつ辞書を取り出せます

```py
for d in H:
    print(d)
```

辞書の値を取り出すならこんな感じ

```py
for j in W:
    print([d[j] for d in H])
```